# Is Redis ReJSON module compatible with Google Memorystore?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-memorystore

Is Redis ReJSON module compatible with Google Memorystore? I want to store JSON in memorystore, can I use ReJSON module?

Comment: if you feel like updating the answer it might be good to? (as it is now supported)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you cannot use the ReJSON module because it's currently not supported to use any modules in Google Cloud Memorystore as [it is running **v3.2.11**](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/redis-overview) and the user modules system was [introduced in Redis **v4.0**](https://redislabs.com/blog/redis-4-0-0-released/). Also in the ReJSON module requirements it stated that it [requires Redis **v4.0** or above](https://oss.redislabs.com/rejson/#building-and-loading-the-module).

Related to this, there is already a [public feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120462224) for Google Cloud Memorystore to release v4.0 in which it is stated that:

> We are working on releasing 4.0 in Q1 (2019). We will follow up with 5.0 shortly after that.

I cannot confirm it but it can be that after the **v4.0** is introduced, you are able to use the ReJSON module.

Answer (score 4):

As of July 13 2020, Memorystore does not support Redis modules, even with the latest Redis version 5.0

Answer (score 2):

Memorystore now supports Redis 4 with a beta tag but they do not support modules: https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/supported-versions#redis_version_40_beta

Answer (score 2):

v6 is compatible. All versions below this are not. Hope this helps.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/supported-versions#redis_version_6x I don't see here, that it supports Redis module in v6

Comment: Can you share any doc related to this